# SELECTING * From a Table But Only Taking One Row with Highest Value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Suppose I have a table with the following schema

Student

| Name | SchoolFees |
| --- | --- |
| James | $23 |
| James | $21 |
| Paul | $36 |
| Tim | $13 |

I am trying to do a SELECT * from this table, but the catch is that I only want to retrieve one row per student, where it's SchoolFees is the highest. So for example, my query should return

| Name | SchoolFees |
| --- | --- |
| James | $23 |
| Paul | $36 |
| Tim | $13 |

How do I go about constructing this query? I am using MariaDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is name and the max of fees, a simple group by is simplest:

```
select name, max(school_fees) from student group by name;
```

However, if you want the record with the max of school_fees and any other fields as well a "window function" may be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
select Name, max(SchoolFees) as SchoolFees from  [Table_Name]
group by Name
```